# Haskell - concatenate two double linked circular lists?

Tags: haskell

So I need to implement doubly linked circular lists in Haskell using the data type:

`type Wheel a = ([a], [a])`

It is set up in such a way that, a pair ([y1,..,yn],[z1,..,zm]) represents a circular lists with elements [y1,..,yn,zm,..,z1]; the element to the right of z1 is y1, the element to the left of y1 is z1. The head element is y1

All operations need to have amortized complexity O(1).

I have implemented most of the operations with amortized complexity O(1), such as moving the head of list (anti-)clockwise, inserting an element and extracting an element, but I cannot figure out how to implement concatenation without reversing at least 1 list.

My current implementation is below:

```
concatW :: Wheel a -> Wheel a -> Wheel a
concatW ([], _) (f, s) = (f, s)
concatW (f, s) ([], _) = (f, s)
concatW (f, s) (f',s') = (f, s' ++ (reverse f') ++ s)
```

Is it possible to do in amortized O(1)?

Comment: It's not really doubly-linked, is it? Some of the elements are linked one way, some of them are linked the other way.

Comment: yeh it's just a circular list really, does that mean it's not possible to do O(1)?

Comment: I daresay it does mean it's not possible.

Comment: I'm not sure about what "concatenation on circular lists" should be. AFAICS, a circular list `[1,2,3]` should be considered equivalent to `[2,3,1]`, since the elements are handled "circularly" so there's no real head nor tail. I guess you are using a different notion of "circular" than what I expected. So, `(xs,ys)` really means `xs++reverse ys` (and only that!), and `concatW (as,bs) (cs,ds)` should mean `as++reverse bs++cs++reverse ds` where the result should be split into `(_,_)` in some way (e.g. as in your last line of code).

Comment: Yeh that makes sense, but `as++reverse bs++cs++reverse ds` isn't O(1), so I can't do that.

Comment: BTW, the line `concatW ([], _) (f, s) = (f, s)` looks wrong. You can't really ignore the `_` part, can you? Ditto for the analogous line. I can't immediately see how to achieve this in amortized O(1), though, unless one considers `normalize (f,s) = (f ++ reverse s, [])` as amortized O(1) (i.e. elements of `s` carry a "discount" of 1 unit of cost each), and somehow `++` is considered to be O(1) too.

Comment: I did `concatW ([], _) (f,s) = (f,s)` because i've set it up to be if it has no head it's therefore empty.

Comment: Shouldn't `([1],[2])` be considered equivalent to `([], [2,1])` ? If you implement "snoc: append a single element at the back" I guess you can construct `([], [2,1])`, right?

Comment: The wheel has to have a head. So in your example, 1 is the head. The head must be in the first list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250410/discussion-between-chi-and-tcotts).